# Framer Motion return drag button

Tags: reactjs, animation, draggable, framer-motion

I have objects that can be moved using drag on framer motion. How can I make a button to return all elements to their initial position?

I tried to do it with animate, but the animation is sharp and ugly. I think this is because when you release the element, it still some time "floats" in space and after the animation continues to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useTransform` hook in Framer Motion. You can set the initial position of each element using the initial prop and then use the `useTransform` hook to update the position of each element based on the state of the button.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { motion, useTransform } from "framer-motion";

const MyComponent = () => {
const [isReset, setIsReset] = useState(false);

const x = useTransform(isReset, [false, true], [0, 100]);
const y = useTransform(isReset, [false, true], [0, 100]);

return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        drag
        style={{ x, y }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5, ease: "easeInOut" }}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setIsReset(true)}>Reset</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! That does sound like an option, but the problem is that the item slides, and after it returns to its original position it goes back to where it was before. Apparently you need to leave the slide effect, but disable it as soon as the item comes back. But I don't know how to do that.